# How do I turn on saving battery when away from notebook?

Tags: windows-10, battery-life

How do I turn on saving battery mode when away from notebook, for say, 2-3 minutes without use? Does windows 10 have something like this natively? if not, what's a good software for this?

Comment: You should enable battery saving permanently. This mode shuts down various devices after periods of time, which you can control individually from Advanced Power Settings. To wait 2-3 minutes before doing this makes no sense.